# How to count the number of elements in a list and create a new column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df as follows:

```
   Col1                                           Col2
    0                                     [7306914, 7306915]
    1                                     [7295911, 7295912]
    2                                              [7324496]
    3                                     [7294109, 7294110]
    4                                              [7313713]
```

The second column is a list. 
what I would like is to create a new column that contains the total number of elements in the list

**Expected Output:**

```
   Col1        Col2           Col3
    0    [7306914, 7306915]      2
    1    [7295911, 7295912]      2
    2    [7324496]               1
    3    [7294109, 7294110]      2
    4    [7313713]               1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html). This is a vectorized method and is more efficient than `apply` function, which is essentially `looping` under-the-hood:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'Col1': 0, 'Col2': [7306914, 7306915]}, {'Col1': 1, 'Col2': [7295911, 7295912]}, {'Col1': 2, 'Col2': [7324496]}, {'Col1': 3, 'Col2': [7294109, 7294110]}, {'Col1': 4, 'Col2': [7313713]}])

df['Col3'] = df['Col2'].str.len()
```

[out]

```
print(df)

   Col1                Col2  Col3
0     0  [7306914, 7306915]     2
1     1  [7295911, 7295912]     2
2     2           [7324496]     1
3     3  [7294109, 7294110]     2
4     4           [7313713]     1
```

Comment: @jezrael it is true yes... https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html

Comment: hmmm, interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
df_tmp = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[[1,2,3], [1,2]]}).reset_index()
In [360]:

df_tmp.head()
Out[360]:
    index   col1
0   0       [1, 2, 3]
1   1       [1, 2]
In [364]:

df_tmp['len'] = df_tmp.apply(lambda x: len(x['col1']), axis=1)
In [365]:

df_tmp
Out[365]:
    index   col1        len
0   0       [1, 2, 3]   3
1   1       [1, 2]      2
```

Apply should be most faster way for that.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `DataFrame.apply()` or `DataFrame.apply()` like this:

```
df['Col3'] = df['Col2'].apply(len)
```

Hope it could help you.